# how to search for particular groups user belongs to

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have file test.txt which contains details of id command ( eg: `id sudi` )

```
uid=23351(sudi) gid=5000(bns) groups=5000(bns),16382(damepgrp),15657(edl_prd_rcrr_sup),15650(edl_prd_rcrr_user),15712(edl_prd_yarn_int_cb),15721(edl_prd_yarn_int_rsk),15632(edl_prod_rcam_admin),16110(edlp_bc5m_sup)

uid=23458(achung1) gid=5000(bns) groups=5000(bns),15757(edl_prd_ice_analyst),15483(edl_prd_ice_user),15650(edl_prd_rcrr_user),15712(edl_prd_yarn_int_cb),15721(edl_prd_yarn_int_rsk)

uid=19831(afabia) gid=5000(bns) groups=5000(bns),15774(edl_prd_c360da_users),15714(edl_prd_yarn_int_ana),15712(edl_prd_yarn_int_cb),15606(edl_prod_c360_users),16179(edl_prod_c360rt_users),15621(edl_prod_dspm_dev),16076(edlp_bc4g_ca_ez_usr),16052(edlp_bc4g_ca_usr),16053(edlp_c360_da_usr),15105(hdpcmo),15104(hdpnanalytics),15279(hdpnaug),15144(rscmo),15280(rsnaug),16171(edl_prod_c360rt_susr)
```

how to print only id and yarn groups as output. I have tried it with grep and sed but no luck
eg:

```
 sudi: edl_prd_yarn_int_ana, edl_prd_yarn_int_cb
 achung1: edl_prd_yarn_int_cb, edl_prd_yarn_int_rsk
 afabia: edl_prd_yarn_int_cb, edl_prd_yarn_int_ana
```

Comment: Will the yarn info always be wrapped in double asterisks?

Comment: no i have just highlighted for the question purpose output of id command is as follows: uid=23351(abotha) gid=5000(bns) groups=5000(bns),16382(damepgrp),15657(edl_prd_rcrr_sup),15650(edl_prd_rcrr_user),15712(edl_prd_yarn_int_cb),15721(edl_prd_yarn_int_rsk),15632(edl_prod_rcam_admin),16110(edlp_bc5m_sup)

Answer (score 0):

Using

`gawk` :

```
$ awk -v RS='[()]' -v OFS=, '/yarn/{s=s?s OFS $1:$1}END{print "sudi: " s}' infile
sudi: edl_prd_yarn_int_ana,edl_prd_yarn_int_cb
```

`awk` :

```
$ awk -F'[()]' -v OFS=, '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)if($i~/yarn/)s=s?s OFS $i:$i}END{print "sudi: " s}' infile
```

***Input:***

```
$ cat infile
uid=21015(sudi) gid=5000(bns) groups=5000(bns),15714(edl_prd_yarn_int_ana),15712(edl_prd_yarn_int_cb),16083(edlp_bc4g_sup),16186(edlp_bc55_ah_da_usr1),16183(edlp_bc55_ah_da_usr2),16134(edlp_bc55_sup),16045(edlp_ds_na_usrgrp),15970(edlp_dsci_usr),15861(edlp_dsna_app),15956(edlp_pricinggtb_susr),15105(hdpcmo),15108(hdpcoe),15104(hdpnanalytics),15144(rscmo),15143(rsnanalytics),15152(rsnanalyticssec),15159(s2hdp19grp)
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep -oP "uid=\d+\(\K\w+(?=\))|\w+yarn\w+" file | awk '$0~/yarn/{if(!first){a=a" "$1; first=1}else{a=a" ,"$0}} $0!~/yarn/{print a; a=$0":"; first=0} END{print a}'`

Output:

```
sudi: edl_prd_yarn_int_cb,edl_prd_yarn_int_rsk
achung1: edl_prd_yarn_int_cb,edl_prd_yarn_int_rsk
afabia: edl_prd_yarn_int_ana,edl_prd_yarn_int_cb
```

Comment: Yeah, that`s the one, what if i have 3 or more strings for yarn

Comment: If each user has 3 strings for yarn then change the paste command to `paste - - - -`. BUT this will not work if users have different number of yarn strings for eg. if user1 has 3 yarn strings and user2 has 4 yarn strings. This will fail in that case. Do you want a generic solution ?

Comment: i have users with 2 , 3, 4 yarn strings eg: uid=23391(xxxx) gid=5000(bns) groups=5000(bns),15714(edl_prd_yarn_int_ana),15712(edl_prd_yarn_int_cb),15718(edl_prd_yarn_int_gbm),16110(edlp_bc5m_sup),15829(edlp_cbt_tsz_ro),15143(rsnanalytics),15152(rsnanalyticssec) this user has 3 yarn strings..so i need a generic one wherein irrespective of number of yarn strings it should work

Comment: Check the updated solution. From next time make sure to put all necessary information in your question and show your efforts also. SO is not a code factory.